# Could the stock price of the target firm fall when a buyout is announced?

Tags: stocks, corporate-acquisition

I've read this: [Why do stocks gap up after a buyout is announced?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/70837) I'm wondering if it's possible for the opposite to occur: could the stock price of a target firm fall when a buyout is announced? What are the conditions under which a fall in price could happen when a company is going to be acquired by another company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The price of a target company to be acquired usually goes up because a premium must be offered to incentivize shareholders to sell. Infrequently, the opposite happens.  I say infrequently because I have maintained a database for 25+ years via a Thomson Reuters subscription and I rarely see it.  I'd guess that if you do a Google search, you'll find some stories out there.

One possibility for a drop in price is that based on rumors, share price has run up past the acquisition price  and the buy out offer is lower.

Another is that it's a stock deal and if the merger is viewed poorly, a drop in the acquirer's price values the acquisition price lower.

Comment: Just curious: is this "Thomson Reuters subscription" an Eikon or some sort of data feed (API)? Isn't such data prohibitively expensive for most of retail?

Comment: The cost depends on the nature of the data (equities, mutual funds, options, EOD,  real time, etc.).  I only subscribe to EOD for equities (stocks and ETFs) and not that I need it, it provides something like 25+ years of historical data, assuming that the security traded back then.  It's not expensive.

Comment: That's interesting. So you called them, told them the kind data you need, and they suggested a subscription product that fit your requirements? Is your subscription display-only, or are you allowed to extract and save data?

Comment: My answer isn't relevant to current technology. I'm a relic from a bygone era. Circa 1990, I went through a technical analysis phase. I bought a DOS charting program called Metastock (and later a Windows version) which stores the data in individual files. I can view any equity for any period of time and can export that data as well. As an example, I have invested and traded preferred stocks for 20+ years. I've written a routine that exports EOD data for about 400 of them and in under 3 minutes it updates 75+ different spreadsheets. I don't know what T-R currently offers. I just auto renew

Comment: What made you quit technical analysis? (I know that we're going off-topic, but I couldn't resist. You're very knowledgeable, and your experiences are interesting)

Comment: Technical analysis provides info like support and resistance, current trend and momentum but the standard indicators they are just a reflection of past price/volume and they predict nothing going forward. It's like looking in the rear view mirror and expecting that to tell you where you are going. Any trade from such analysis is based on the HOPE that whatever trend or momentum you have identified will continue. That's not to say that some don't succeed with it but IMHO, the vast majority are just spewing esoteric BS. It has spawned an industry of get rich easy software /newsletters, etc.

Comment: cont.  The next time someone tries to convince you that technical analysis is the road to riches, ask them to provide their real time recommendations that can be monitored for performance.  The silence will likely be deafening or if not, worthless.  As for me, I found more reliable ways to trade.